# How can one choose a new kernel on boot, running a dedicated server?

Tags: linux, debian, grub, proxmox

As part of installing proxmox on a dedicated server running Debian, it installed a new kernel. As part of the install instructions, I am supposed to choose the new kernel in grub. However I dont have a virtual console for accessing the server at the time of boot. The only thing I can do, is to run an ssh console to the server after it boots. How can I select the pv kernel as default for boot time?

I am running Debian Wheezy on the server, and installed proxmox 3.

Comment: "server" and no virtual console? Bad - maybe return it to the seller and ask for a server? What do you do if you need to reinstall totally, or do a bios upgrade? Remoete viortual consoles are standard even on low end servers these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `GRUB_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`. You can use the title of the kernel entry instead of an index, so it's not disturbed by subsequent kernel installs/removals. Then you need to run `update-grub`. From the [Grub manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration):

```
‘GRUB_DEFAULT’
The default menu entry. This may be a number, in which case it identifies the
Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero, or the title of a menu entry,
or the special string ‘saved’. Using the title may be useful if you want to set
a menu entry as the default even though there may be a variable number of entries 
before it.

For example, if you have:

     menuentry 'Example GNU/Linux distribution' --class gnu-linux {
     ...
     }

then you can make this the default using:

    GRUB_DEFAULT='Example GNU/Linux distribution'

If you set this to ‘saved’, then the default menu entry will be that saved by
‘GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT’, grub-set-default, or grub-reboot.
```

Comment: How to get the title of the kernel entry?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen On my system you can do it with this command: `grep "menuentry " /boot/grub/grub.cfg|cut -d"'" -f2`. But I don't know if it's universal, and if you have submenus it may also be different. You can also just look at the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
set default="X"
```

where X is an index number of kernel definition in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: But that will be reset on running a update-grub, wont it?

Answer (score 0):

There's `grub-set-default`(8) which can be used to select the boot entry if you're using `savedefault`. If you're not using `savedefault` the default is `set default="0"` which boots the first defined kernel. Usually the kernels are ordered from latest to oldest in order to boot into the latest kernel.